# How to call images in a database into 10 images per row?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, jpeg

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM champicons") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

echo "<table border='10' width='100%' cellpadding='10' >"; 
echo "<tr>";  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "<td>";  
}  
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";          


?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for 10 images to be put in 1 row before dropping a row below and making another 10 images appear, right now the more images I put into the database the wider and smaller the current row gets and I can't see all the images.

It's hard to get it to create a new row at 10 images as the images are called on a while loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to make my images called from a database to be a link to another page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366910/possible-to-make-my-images-called-from-a-database-to-be-a-link-to-another-page)

Comment: ^-- Your other question. You edited it and wrote "EDIT: SOLVED". So, what's the scoop with this one? Two questions related to each other in less than an hour.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, I thought the questions weren't that related to ask both in one, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter before the loop and if in the loop.

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "</td>";
    if($i++%10 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it involved a counter! I changed the i=1 to i=0 as it was only calling the first 9 for the first row as it was already set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to count your iteration and insert new row according

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "</td>";  
    $i++;
    if($i==10){
        $i=1;
        echo "</tr><tr>";  
    }
}
```

As side note your `</td>` wasn't closed correctly

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering why I had a cell padding look to my table, didn't even spot the </td> error, this fixed it thanks :)