# Possible to make my images called from a database to be a link to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink, navigation

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM champicons ") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' width='100%' >"; 
echo "<tr>";  
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    if($i++%10 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "</td>";


}  
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";          

?>
```

I'm calling 117 images which are small icons into a table with 10 images per row, I want these images to be links to a specific page for each image, is this possible through the way I have my code now?

EDIT: Example

Picture 1 links to /picture1.php
Picture 2 links to /picture2.php
etc.

EDIT: SOLVED

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    if($i++%10 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
    $name = $row[1];
    $image = $row[2];
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='$name'>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';   
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
```

Comment: no, images can't "be links". But you can wrap them in an `<a>` tag which WILL do that. `<a href="otherpage?id=foo"><img ... /></a>`

Comment: Are the images linking to themselves or a different page?

Comment: If the same table contains the url to link to for each image, there should be no problem wrapping the image in an `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add an anchor tag around the image.

```
echo "<td>";
   echo "<a href='url here'>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';  
   echo "</a>"; 
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: But I have 117 images, in a loop that would only suffice for 1 image.

Comment: this should be part of your `while()` which is the loop over all your images

Comment: Thanks this solved it with a slight change thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `image.php` file. In the file, create a function that will parse an ID from the URL. In your table of images, link them to `/images.php?Id=thepictureid`